# how to port android application to blackberry 7.1 os

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I have an android app and i want to port it to blackberry.
Studies showed dat procedure port android app to BB 10os which can't run on previous BB platforms, Is there any way that android app can be ported to BB 7.1os?

Answer (score 1):

The Android runtime for BlackBerry exists only on PlayBook and BlackBerry 10 which can easily repackage your APK file9s).  For BlackBerry 7.1 OS (which is uses J2ME), the developer would need to re-write a lot of code to port the app from J2SE to J2ME